# (Python) word replacement program using a dictionary, making only the first word applied

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

The word replacement source code is as follows.

```
text ="""
abc1 aaaaaa aaaaaaaa abc2 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa abc3 aaaaaaa abc1 aaaaaa aaaaaaaa abc2 aaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaa abc3 aaaaaaa abc1 aaaaaa aaaaaaaa abc2 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa abc3 aaaaaaa abc1 aaaaaaa
"""

dictionary = {"abc1":"apple", "abc2":"banana", "abc3":"tomato"}

pattern = "|".join(rf"\b{x}\b" for x in dictionary.keys())
s = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: dictionary[x.group()], text)
print(s)
```

This will replace all elements. What I want is that each element of the dictionary is replaced only once. For example, like below

```
apple aaaaaa aaaaaaaa banana aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa tomato aaaaaaa abc1 aaaaaa aaaaaaaa abc2 aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaa abc3 aaaaaaa abc1 aaaaaa aaaaaaaa abc2 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa abc3 aaaaaaa abc1 aaaaaaa
```

Only the first element is replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fourth count parameter to `re.sub` to tell the API to only do a single replacement:

```py
dictionary = {"abc1":"apple", "abc2":"banana", "abc3":"tomato"}

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    text = re.sub(r'\b' + key + r'\b', value, text, 1)
print(text)
```

This prints:

```
apple aaaaaa aaaaaaaa banana aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa tomato aaaaaaa abc1 aaaaaa aaaaaaaa abc2 aaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaa abc3 aaaaaaa abc1 aaaaaa aaaaaaaa abc2 aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa abc3 aaaaaaa abc1 aaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 1):

You might harness `dict`'s method `.pop` with 2 arguments, consider following example:

```
dictionary = {"abc1":"apple", "abc2":"banana", "abc3":"tomato"}
print(dictionary.pop("abc1", "default"))
print(dictionary.pop("abc1", "default"))
print(dictionary.pop("abc1", "default"))
```

output

```
apple
default
default
```

In your case 2nd argument should be was matched (as `str`), so

```
s = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: dictionary.pop(x.group(),x.group()), text)
```

should work